# Cant connect to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have information for some AWS. When I log in I go to AWS management control and then I open EC2. I am just trying to make simple ssh or ftp to the server, so I can change some things on some website which is hosted there.

I added private key that I made in AWS and try to ssh to AWS but it is looking for some publik key. Where can I found that>

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: btw I am using Mac if that is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you created the machine there is no need to access AWS Console to ssh into the instance.

1) Make sure you have the pem file used to create the instance
2) Open a terminal window
3) SSH into your instance. ssh -i you_pem_file.pem root@ip_address_of_your_ec2

If you lost the pem file, well, you're kind of lost :) In this case, you can go to the EC2 AWS Console, create an AMI from the instance you have lost your PEM file, create a new keypair,  and launch a new instance from the AMI with the just created keypair.